# Get session ID of Magento using SAOP API in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, magento

```
NSString *soapMessage = @" \
    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> \
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"           xmlns:ns1=\"urn:Magento\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\"> 
\<SOAP-ENV:Body> \

    <ns1:login> \
    <username xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">XXXX</username> \
    <apiKey xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">123456</apiKey> \
    </ns1:login> \
    </SOAP-ENV:Body> \
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

NSString *url = @"http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/Magento/api/soap/?wsdl";


    [urlConnection urlConnection:soapMessage url:url];
    [urlConnection setTarget:self withValidSelector:@selector(jsonData:) invalidSelector:@selector(error)];

In urlConnection

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postString length]];
    [request addValue:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/magento/" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Above is my code. It returns lot of XML tag with html not SESSION ID.

Answer (score 1):

Remove "?wsdl" from your url "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/Magento/api/soap/?wsdl".

Used this url "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/Magento/api/soap/"

It will return SESSION ID.